# Equality between 2 summations unclear

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm learning about integrals and in particular upper and lower Riemann sums. Now in an example I came about the following:

$$L(f, P_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i - 1})^2\Delta x = \frac{a^3}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i - 1)^2 =\ ...$$

I don't understand how this equality comes about, in particular $\frac{a^3}{n^3}$ seem to appear out of thin air at the moment.

Any hints, definitions or theorems I shoud consult to get a feeling for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are integrating $x^2$ with respect to $x$ from $x=0$ to $x=a$, you divide the area into $n$ strips of width $\Delta x=\frac an$ unit each. Your $x_{i-1}$ is consequently $x_{i-1}=(i-1)\Delta x =\frac{a}{n}(i-1)$, so you have $(x_{i-1})^2=\left(\frac{a}{n}(i-1)\right)^2$. Simplifying, you have
$$(x_{i - 1})^2\Delta x = \frac{a^3}{n^3}(i - 1)^2 $$